# Cannot SSH to MY EC2 From any network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I Cannot SSH to MY EC2 From any network ( my home-network, my workplace, or my Linode box) or ping the EC2 instance. I have all the necessary ports open, inbound and outbound. My IP address is 54.89.239.56, And the instance is RUNNING What could this be.**

**Inbound** 
SSH TCP  22 0.0.0.0/0

SSH TCP 22 ::/0

All ICMP - IPv4 All N/A 0.0.0.0/0

All ICMP - IPv4 All N/A ::/0

**Outbound**
 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Have you _ever_ managed to SSH into the instance? Did you just launch it? Which AMI did you use? Is it in a public subnet? Can you SSH to any other instances in the same subnet? You'll need to provide more information than just "I cannot SSH".

Answer (score 3):

The standard things to always check when attempting to connect from the Internet to an EC2 instance are:

- **Internet Gateway** attached to the VPC
- You are referencing the instance via a **Public IP Address**
- Instance was launched in a **public subnet**, which means that the subnet is associated to a Route Table that routes to the Internet Gateway
- **Security Group** is permitting the inbound traffic from your IP Address and port (outbound traffic configuration is irrelevant because Security Groups are stateful)
- **Network ACL** is not blocking the traffic (by default it permits all inbound and outbound traffic)
- The instance is **listening on the port** (eg Linux SSH on port 22, Windows RDP on port 3389)
- There are **no host-based firewalls on the instance** blocking traffic (eg Windows Firewall)